# Magento 2 how to set constructor argument?

Tags: magento2, construct

I am trying to find out how I can send constructor argument when calling class. This is what I tried:

```
     class Subscriber extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{
            protected $mailchimp;
            protected $phpmailer;
            ...
            public function __construct(
                \Vendorname\Modulename\Lib\Mailchimp $mailchimp,
                \Vendorname\Modulename\Lib\Phpmailer $phpmailer,
                ...
            ){
                parent::__construct($context,$registry);
                $this->mailchimp = $mailchimp('MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE')
            }
            function subscribe(){
                $this->mailchimp->subscribe();
            }
```

Mailchimp class:

```
    namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Lib\Mailchimp;

    class Mailchimp
    {
        $private apiKey;
        public function __construct($apiKey=false)
        {
```

But it is giving me error `Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string`. What is a proper way to send argument?

Comment: check this screen-short i think this problem --- https://prnt.sc/snjijv

Comment: tnx, but this was just mistake when I copied code here, actual code has two (__) operators.